# Where authorities in PoA are stored?

Tags: go-ethereum, proof-of-authority

I am trying to deploy a private `ethereum` network in my machine using **Proof-Of-Authority** and `geth` client. 
I followed this [tutorial](https://hackernoon.com/setup-your-own-private-proof-of-authority-ethereum-network-with-geth-9a0a3750cda8) but I can't realize where the information about authorities are stored?

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `sealers` in the genesis file and `athorities` are nothing but `sealers`.

Comment: Ok, where sealers are stored ?

Comment: Genesis block is the first block of the blockchain. If any node is added newly in the blockchain it will have to sync with the nodes which were previously there in the blockchain. So information about sealers there in every participating nodes of the blockchain network.

Comment: I was not asking about genesis block. it seems like you didn't understand my question ;) .. the answer is in "extraData"

Comment: what is "extraData" ? This is new to me too.

Comment: it is a filed in the genesis block that contains the informations about sealers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:  sealers are sealers are stored in the field **extraData**